# Can I use asyncio.wait_for() as a context manager?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Why wouldn't this work:

```
try:
    async with asyncio.wait_for(aiohttp.get(url), 2) as resp:
        print(resp.text())
except asyncio.TimeoutError as e:
    pass
```

Gives

```
async with asyncio.wait_for(aiohttp.get(url), 2) as resp:
AttributeError: __aexit__
```

To my understanding, `asyncio.wait_for()` would pass the future of `aiohttp.get()`, which has an `__aenter__` and `__aexit__` method (as is demonstrated by the fact that `async with aiohttp.get()` works).

Comment: You should remove the `async` when using `wait_for`.

Comment: Why? `asyncio.wait_for` is a coroutine. But nevertheless, then I get an AttributeError for `__exit__`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot write `async with wait_for(...)` -- `wait_for` doesn't support asynchronous context manager.

I'll add `Timeout` class to `asyncio` soon -- see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-tulip/aRc3VBIXyRc conversation.

For now you can try `aiohttp.Timeout` (it requires installing a fat enough package though) -- or just copy these 40 lines of code.

Interesting thing: the approach doesn't require `async with` -- just old good `with` is enough.

**UPD** I missed that you use aiohttp already.
Thus just follow the second example from [aiohttp timeouts chapter](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/stable/client.html#timeouts).