# Adding a timeout to an Asynchronous Context Manager

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Python [asynchronous context managers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-context-managers-and-async-with) are useful, but they [do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693678/can-i-use-asyncio-wait-for-as-a-context-manager/34694169#34694169) with [asyncio.wait_for Timeouts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for).

*What is the best way to add a Timeout to an asynchronous context manager?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to add a Timeout to an asynchronous context manager?

You can't apply `wait_for` to an async context manager, but you can apply it to a coroutine that uses it. So to add timeout to a context manager, use it in an async function, and apply timeout to that. For example:

```
async def download(url, session):
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        return await resp.text()

async def print_google(session):
    try:
        text = await asyncio.wait_for(download('http://www.google.com', session), 1)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        text = None
    print(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [async-timeout](https://github.com/aio-libs/async-timeout#async-timeout)? Just wrap any async code (including usage of asynchronous context managers) with `async with timeout()`:

```
import asyncio
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

from async_timeout import timeout


@asynccontextmanager
async def my_acm():
    print('before')
    yield
    print('after')


async def main():
    async with timeout(1):
        async with my_acm():
            await asyncio.sleep(1.5)


asyncio.run(main())
```

If you want to apply timeout to async context manager only, you can create new context manager that utilizes `async-timeout`:

```
import asyncio
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

from async_timeout import timeout


@asynccontextmanager
async def my_acm():
    print('before')
    yield
    print('after')


@asynccontextmanager
async def my_acm_plus_timeout(time):
    async with timeout(time):
        async with my_acm():
            yield


async def main():
    async with my_acm_plus_timeout(1):
        await asyncio.sleep(1.5)


asyncio.run(main())
```